# ASP.Net Localization Double Byte characters to HtmlEncode or UTF-8

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, localization

We got requirement to convert "windows-1251" double byte character to "UTF-8" but not able to do in ASP.NET

Example Text:  Ïðåäîñòàâëåíèå óñëóã
Expected output: Предоставление услуг

In classic asp  following line `<META http-equiv=Content-type content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>` in header section will convert neatly however my requirement to implement the same in ASP.Net pages.

1)  I have tried adding charset in response header, but not converting as expected output.

Response.Charset = "windows-1251"

Appreciated any help on this,

Thanks & Regards,
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

Try web.config globalization tag:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```